# What's the asymptotic complexity of this pseudocode?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, pseudocode, asymptotic-complexity

could you plese tell me the asymptotic complexity of this code?

```
f(n):
if (n<=2) then return 1;
else { 
     if (n>950) then { i=n/2; return f(i);}
     else return f(n-2);
}
```

I have thought of two solutions.

a)

```
O(1)         when n<=2
T(n/2) + 1   when n > 950
T(n-2) + 1   when 950>=n>2
```

and solving the recurrences:

```
O(1)         when n<=2
Θ(log n)     when n > 950
O(n^2)       when 950>=n>2
```

b) However I'm not so sure about the complexity of the last two statements, because if n is bigger than 950 the alghorithm will call f(i) until i is smaller than 950 and then proceed calling f(n-2).
So, the other solution is this one:

```
O(1)                  when n<=2
T(n/2) + T(n-2) + 1   otherwise
```

and solving the recurrences:

```
O(1)         when n<=2
O(n^2)       otherwise
```

I actually think the second one is right, but I'm not sure of it. 
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

okay, so start by thinking about what happens if n is *really* big.  Eventually n will be big enough it will dominate everything else.  And sure enough, until you get down to n=950 you're going to get O(lg n) where "lg" denotes log base 2. (Why do I know this off hand?because the size of n decreases by a power of two every iteration.)

Once n is down to 950, then it's going to decrease by 2 every time, so from 950 to 2 is O(n) -- because you hit basically half the values and that 1/2 disappears into the constant.

But observe that there exists a value of n for which lg n > 950/2.  Ergo the lg n term will dominate for some value of n.  O(lg n).

Answer (score 2):

O(1) for n<=2.

O(1) for 2 < n <= 950 - it takes constant time (950/2).

T(n/2) for n>950.

So you get: T(n) = T(n/2) + 0(1).

Total complexity = O(log n).

Answer (score 0):

Asymptotic behaviour is a description of the growth of the complexity, it's not a function that you can plug individual values of *n* into.  So it doesn't make sense to have two or three different statements for different values of *n*.

Consider that as *n* -> infinity, the behaviour for *n* < 950 becomes negligible.